# Filtering JSON from API through jq in Python

Tags: python, json, api, spotify, jq

I'm trying to filter out the field "name" to store in a file. I'm filtering like so:

```
r =requests.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/70yMNdgyIj9SrQXFmdJKx9', 
headers=headers)

print(jq(".[name]").transform(json.loads(r)))
```

I get the error:     print(jq(".[name]").transform(text=r))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Any help on the matter? The documentation for jq python bindings is not very clear to me https://pypi.org/project/jq/

Comment: Have you noticed that the `jq` module was advertised as *beta* level on pypi?

Comment: slightly off-topic, but a nice jq filter builder out of data could be found here: https://github.com/ilyash/show-struct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the exception message states, you are trying to call a module.

You have probably used `import jq` instead of `from jq import jq`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!